При запуске приложения необходимо, чтобы выполнялись mysql команды
Мне необходимо, чтобы при запуске приложения выполнялись следующие mysql команды по типу:
CREATE USER 'user'@'82.202.199.34' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE DATABASE my_timeweb;

Кто-нибудь знает что-то подобное? Если да, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Это подразумевает административный доступ к СУБД, а так делать однозначно НЕ нужно. Такие действия должен выполнять администратор вручную при установке приложения (а не при запуске)

мне нужно авто создание базы даных она будет взаимодействывать с пайтон нужна автоматизацыя

Создание базы данных - задача не приложения, а администратора. Администратор может автоматизировать свою работу, но к приложению это отношения не имеет и не должно иметь

@andreymal, я не уверен, что единственно правильное - это прямо вот так категорично - только админ. Инсталлятор приложения вполне может создавать БД, а само приложение накатывать на БД изменения структуры в зависимости от версии или получая обновления. Просто необходимо оценить риски и принять их или не принять

@AlexanderSt инсталлятор — это не приложение, он запускается администратором, всё в полном соответствии с моей категоричностью ¯\(ツ)/¯ Ну а для изменения структуры БД административный доступ и не нужен

@Hit, в зависимости от платформы это можно сделать немного разными способами, но в основе - Вы создаете SQL-скрипт, содержащий необходимые Вам инструкции по созданию БД, например my_super_script.sql, а потом применяете его: mysql < my_super_script.sql из bat-файла или sh-скрипта

@andreymal, меня смутило Ваше "вручную"
